# Validando caixa de texto

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Sempre quando faço uma validação em javascript de uma caixa de texto, para saber se  ela está vazia ou não, faço da seguinte maneira:

```
function validar(){
    var input = document.getElementById("texto");
    if(input.value == ""){

         alert("Preencha todos os campos em branco.")

    }
}
```

Contudo, hoje descobri que isto tem uma falha, caso o usuário deixe na caixa de texto um espaço como este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

... e validar o formulário não irá reconhecer como vazia.

Apesar de ser possível fazer isso:

```
function validar(){
    var input = document.getElementById("texto");
    if((input.value == "") || (input.value == " ")){
         alert("Preencha todos os campos em branco.")
    }
}
```

.. e sabendo que existem essas soluções mirabolantes, preciso saber se é possível verificar se há algum caractere dentro da caixa de texto. E uma forma de fazer em javascript puro.

Comment: Um espaço é um caractere, assim como um `. e ,` que pela sua verificação seriam válidos. Seria mais interessante você usar uma regra de validação ou definir um numero minimo de char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para não aceitar espaços em branco, que passam na linha que sugeri em cima pode usar `/^\s*$/.test(input.value);`. Essa expressão regular vai procurar espaços em branco 1 ou mais vezes e testar o input para ver se está vazio. Dá `true` se estiver vazio.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Thp6/1/

---

Se quer ser rígido pode usar `(input.valuelength + '') == 0`. Assim verifica se o input está mesmo vazio. Aqui espaços em branco são aceites.

Comment: Você pode me mostrar um exemplo funcional disto?

Comment: Juntei exemplo para poder testar.